# cannot resole file in <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory> in pom file of spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

in this spring boot back-end project, the ide gives an error which says "cannot resolve file in  **src/main/java**"
how to fix this error
thanks in advance

[image: cannot resole file in <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>]

Comment: Try ../src/main/java

Comment: Remove as you use the default project structure